# How to access array data set to protected in API response

Tags: php, protected

I'm trying to access data from an external API that handles payments. The returned data is structured as below, but I struggle accessing the data inside the data:protected.

```
Payment Object
(
[payments_array:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Payment Object
            (
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 123455
                        [date] => 2017-04-27
                        [payment_method] => paypal
                        [amount_cents] => 6900
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Anyone who could point me in the right direction to make that work?

Comment: Check the API documentation?

Comment: That is imposible to say w/o the actual definition of the object (at least not in a useful manner).